# Помогите составить SQL-запрос (извлечение первой и последней цены за период)

Tags: sql, mysql

**Дано:** Есть таблица "trades", с полями: id, price, time. Каждую минуту в таблицу поступает 0..+бесконечность записей.

**Извлечь:** записи за последние 60 минут, где каждая запись будет содержать статистику за каждую минуту:

- l - минимальная цена на промежутке
- h - максимальная цена на промежутке
- o - цена открытия (самая первая цена)
- c - цена закрытия (самая последняя цена)

(должно извлечься 60 записей)

**Решение (неуд.):**

```
SELECT
    MIN(price) AS l,
    MAX(price) AS h,
    (SELECT price FROM trades
        WHERE time BETWEEN (FLOOR(t.time/60) AND FLOOR(t.time/60)+59
        ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1) AS o,
    (SELECT price FROM trades
        WHERE time BETWEEN (FLOOR(t.time/60) AND FLOOR(t.time/60)+59
        ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) AS c,
    time,
    FLOOR(time/60) AS minute
FROM trades t
WHERE time BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY minute
ORDER BY minute ASC
```

Проблема в извлечении первой и последней цены за период. Для их извлечения использовались подзапросы. Данная конструкция вешает сервер MySQL.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, более удачное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select mm.minute, 
  min(tmm.price) as min_price, max(tmm.price) as max_price,
  t_o.price as o_price, t_c.price as c_price
from
  (select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid, EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE from time) as minute
    from trades
    group by EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE from time)) as mm 
  join trades t_o on mm.minid = t_o.id
  join trades t_c on mm.maxid = t_c.id
  join trades tmm on EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE from tmm.time)=mm.minute
group by mm.minute;
```

Предполагается, что id идут строго по возрастанию (если не так, то надо через time решать, но если там будут дубли все будет плохо).
`EXTRACT` тут используется для идентификации минуты, это может быть и любая другая функция, здесь год например не учитывается.
Фильтр по `time between...` добавите сами.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c23c/2)

Есть еще вариант (более логичный): рассчитывать минуту для каждой записи при вставке, чтоб ее не считать каждый раз. Тогда `EXTRACT(...)` заменяется на эту колонку, повесить на нее индекс, будет гарантировано быстро.